# how to get the jquery id value using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("Time has ended");
            $("#registration-form").submit()
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);

    return new Date();
}

jQuery(function($) {
    s = 10;
    var Minutes = 60 * s,
        display = $('#time');

    var startDate = startTimer(Minutes, display);

    $('button').click(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        var seconds = (now.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
        $('#runtimes').append('<p>' + seconds + '</p>');
    })
});

</script>
<div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="test">Time Left <span id="time"></span>min</div>
</div>

<form name="frmRegistration" id="registration-form" method="post" action="index1.php">
  <div id="runtimes" name="runtime"></div>
<button>Get run time</button>

</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aruncool/vj84mc40/ 
 in the link  displays the value of the already runned time on button click i need to pass the div id value through post and get it into another page and insert the value into db but it is not passing value through the post help me how to get the div id value

Comment: which div and which div id?

Comment: <div id="runtimes" name="runtime"></div>

Comment: want to append value in that div?

Comment: As I said in the other question, you have to use an **input**. Divs are not form elements: https://jsfiddle.net/vj84mc40/2/

Comment: what exactly do you expect the div to do? it has no form function, add an input with the value = the value you what to save or better yet, remove the from and make a $.post() call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an hidden input in your form and update his value when you want.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="valueoftime" name="valueoftime">
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('button').click(
        var now = new Date();
        var seconds = (now.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
        $('#runtimes').append('<p>' + seconds + '</p>');

       //Update input val
        $("#valueoftime").val(seconds);
    })
```